Vita Nostra est quad cognictationes nostra facere est
Translate to English
Vita Nostra est quad cognictationes nostra facere est

It's bad Latin even without the misspellings you added to it.

This a bad transcription of fake Latin made by someone who knew no Latin at all for a government website which, if I didn't know otherwise, I would have sworn was a crack group of cranks. Actually, I don't know otherwise.
They say it means "our life is what our thoughts make it.", but it means no such thing. They unfortunately used Google Translate 10 years ago, which is terrible with Latin, as we have at length discussed before.
For one, it's straight calque from English without any thought given to how Latin speakers have said it. The grammar of the first sentence (which you don't give) is incomprehensible, and there's a missing letter in mutao.
(N.B. I did see a "corrected" seal with a real Latin word here [PDF link], but the misspelled word is still up on their official website.)
In the sentence you give, there's lack of agreement between the noun and its adjective (cogitationes and nosta), and then the subject and the verb (cogitationes and est). And then there's this weird infinitive which is unconnected from everything else. I suppose they're trying to say "thoughts make", but then since it's inside a relative clause, you'd need to conjugate it (faciunt) and then est becomes useless.
The motto is a travesty of good Latin mottoes connected with august institutions, and, frankly, it calls into credibility the whole endeavor.
